# how to get the value of a defined name in another workbook, using vba for excel

Tags: excel, named-ranges, vba

I have several workbooks containing calculations and I am making an "automatic overview" combining the data in all those sheets. To find the data I use named ranges. These work fine.
However there is one defined name that does not refer to a range. It is a formula.

What I want is to access the result from that formula (in an **open** calculations book) from my overview book.

Obviously `wb.Names("myNamedFormula").RefersToRange` does not work as the name does not refer to a range.
`wb.Names("myNamedFormula").Value` gives me the formula, but not the result. None of the name's members gets the result.
I tried evaluating the formula using `Evaluate(...)` but this doesn't work as it should be evaluated in the other workbook.

Does anyone know how to get the result?

Thanks,

ps: I know one possibility is to make the name refer to a range and then do the calculation there, but I don't want that.

Comment: can you post what your formula is? I am playing with this and not getting any of the problems you are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you will have to use Worksheet.Evaluate rather than Application.evaluate (note that all references in the Named Formula should be fully qualified absolute references). Try this syntax for Evaluate

```
ansa = Workbooks("Book1.xlsb").Worksheets(1).Evaluate(Workbooks("Book1.xlsb").Names("AddNumbers").RefersTo)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit of a cludge, but:

Add a formual to a cell in the calculation wb `=MyNamedFormula`  (Lets assume as an example cell A1 on Sheet1)

Add a Name in calculation wb `PointsToMyNamedFormula` that refers to `Sheet1!A1`

Then you can reference `wb.Names("PointsToMyNamedFormula").RefersToRange.Value1`